# Won't Rust allow me to lend a variable twice?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Just beginning my journey to learn Rust.

I have this little piece of code:

```
fn main() {
  simple_logger::init_with_env().unwrap();

  let context = libusb::Context::new().unwrap();
  log::debug!("Created a USB context");
  log::trace!("Trying to find a KA3 device");

  match find_ka3(&context) {
    None => {
      log::error!("Could not find a KA3 device, nothing can be done.");
      return;
    }
    Some(ka3_info) => do_stuff(&ka3_info)
  }
}
```

It fails to compile with these errors:

```
error[E0597]: `context` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:18
   |
18 |   let context = libusb::Context::new().unwrap();
   |       ------- binding `context` declared here
...
22 |   match find_ka3(&context) {
   |         ---------^^^^^^^^-
   |         |        |
   |         |        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
...
29 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `context` dropped here while still borrowed
   | ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Option<KA3Info<'_>>`
   |
help: consider adding semicolon after the expression so its temporaries are dropped sooner, before the local variables declared by the block are dropped
   |
28 |   };
   |    +
```

I found two ways to fix it by experimenting. Way #1:

```
fn main() {
  simple_logger::init_with_env().unwrap();

  let context = libusb::Context::new().unwrap();
  log::debug!("Created a USB context");
  log::trace!("Trying to find a KA3 device");

  match find_ka3(&context) {
    None => {
      log::error!("Could not find a KA3 device, nothing can be done.");
      return;
    }
    Some(ka3_info) => do_stuff(&ka3_info)
  }; // This semi-colon ends the borrowing?
}
```

Way #2

```
fn main() {
  simple_logger::init_with_env().unwrap();

  let context = libusb::Context::new().unwrap();
  log::debug!("Created a USB context");
  log::trace!("Trying to find a KA3 device");

  let find_result = find_ka3(&context);
  match find_result {
    None => {
      log::error!("Could not find a KA3 device, nothing can be done.");
      return;
    }
    Some(ka3_info) => do_stuff(&ka3_info)
  }
}
```

While I am glad I figured out a solution I'd like somebody to explain *why* these two satisfied the borrow-checker. For way #1 I am not sure why adding a semi-colon fixes things, and for way #2 I am stumped as to how in-lining the call on the `match` is different to supplying the result of the call on a variable.

Comment: What's `find_ka3()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1 omitting the semicolon is an implicit return of the `match` expression, meaning that the value could potentially be used *after* the function main returns (and this does not *always* signify program exit so the compiler cannot assume such). So adding the `;` changes the return type of main to be `()` and the checker knows the value isn't being used after main returns. Stuff like this is why it's usually a good idea to explicitly annotate your function signatures.

For #2 it changes which lifetime is under consideration: it is now the lifetime of the *owned* `find_result` rather than the *borrow* of `context`: in the second example the checker knows you're done with `context` immediately after `let find_result = find_ka3(&context);`

Comment: Thank you for the easy explanation, that makes a ton of sense.